# Session score post to database

Tags: php, mysql, session

This is just a general question...not help me with my code one.
I've created a dynamic quiz for a project that pulls questions and choices from my database and generates total score in a $_SESSION and displays it to a user at the end of the quiz to see how well they did.

I want to get that score and display it in a lovely leaderboard/ high scores table. Is it possible to pull that data from $_SESSION ? Or should I store scores in database as well and then retriving it from it to display?

Thanks!

Comment: Session data is only available for the current user, so if your leaderboard needs to include other users' high scores, you'll need a database

Comment: You could very well display it on a fancy leaderboard using $_SESSION. However, that's not really secure and you wouldn't be able to use other player's score. So, using a database would be the way to go.

Comment: Thought that, thank you guys ;)